# How can I mount a vent louver to a partially obstructed round duct?

Tags: walls, vent, ventilation

I need to install a wall vent in my kitchen. The problem is that the hole is not round! Do I cut a plastic vent or what type of wall vent do I install? Thanks for any tips!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not important that the louver fit the duct, generally speaking. I would just install a square or rectangular louver of adequate size, positioned tight to the perpendicular surface we see here.

[image]